# G-code firmware for handheld plotter (Arduino)

Tags: reprap, repetier

I'd like to build a plotter to work without a PC (power supply by battery).
Plotter will write only several numbers on a card (really short G-code).

Do you know any firmware, which can be easily modified for this reason?
Or do you know G-code library which could be easily implemented into my stepper controller in Arduino?

My plan is to use Repetier (printing from SD), but I prefer to print without SD.
Repetier is also too big, there are a lot of functions that I don't need.

Comment: Have you found & fixed the problem? If any of the answers helped you to get an answer to your question or come to your own conclusions then please do vote & accept an answer (using the tick button next to it). This helps us reduce the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) & stops the question from being bumped once in a while. If you found another answer (than those already posted), please add that answer (& accept after 48 hours) to share your experience with the community. If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

Answer (score 4):

Your question **may** be useful to people interested in 3d printing (the purpose of this SE Site) so, even though you're not asking a 3d printing question per se, I think this answer will be helpful...

**GRBL:**

GRBL is a well known and mature g-code interpreter that will run on an Arduino Uno and is free and open source.  [Check it out here.](https://github.com/grbl/grbl/wiki)

I hope this helps!  :-)